# Reset persisted stated of an application State managed with Zustand

Tags: zustand

I'm trying to remove all user data from the persisted state, when a user logs out. For managing my state I'm using Zustand and followed this guide: https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/typescript

I'm creating my store as follows:

```
export const useStore = create<Slices>()(
  persist(
    devtools((...x) => ({
      ...createProfileSlice(...x),
      ...createSessionSlice(...x),
      ...createStatusSlice(...x),
    })),
    {
      name: CONFIGURATION.STATE.NAME,
      partialize: (state) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(state).filter(([key]) => !['session', 'isLoading'].includes(key))),
    }
  )
);
```

My question is now, how to remove all data from the persisted store, when a user logs out. I've tried to clear the localstorge with `localstorage.clear()`, but Zustand sets the whole state when the next change at the state is done again.

I've also found the following guide: https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/how-to-reset-state
This guide uses another structure and honestly I don't understand what is going on. How can I delete all user data from the persisted state when a user logs out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a piece of a cake. as the [docs](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/slices-pattern#updating-multiple-stores) says about updating multiple stores in slicing patterns:

you create a slice to make changes in multiple slices :

```
import { createBearSlice } from './bearSlice'
import { createFishSlice } from './fishSlice'

export const resetAllSlices = (set) => ({
  resetAll: () => {
    createBearSlice(set).reset()
    createFishSlice(set).reset()
  },
})
```

then import this slice to your main store:

```
import { create } from 'zustand'
import { createBearSlice } from './bearSlice'
import { createFishSlice } from './fishSlice'
import { resetAllSlices } from './resetAllSlices'

export const useBoundStore = create((...a) => ({
  ...createBearSlice(...a),
  ...createFishSlice(...a),
  ...resetAllSlices(...a),
}))
```

and use it in a component like below:

```
export const myComponent = ()=>{
  const resetState = useStore((state) => state.resetAll);

  resetState();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will leave it here in case someone else faces the same problem; I got the same problem. Here is how I solved it

````
export const useAuth = create(
  persist(
    (set) => ({
      user: {},
      setUser: (user) =>
        set(() => ({
          user: user,
        })),
      logout: () => {
        set(() => ({ user: null }));
        localStorage.removeItem("auth")<------- to remove data from localstorage
      }
    }),
    {
      name: "auth",
    }
  )
); ```


hope this help !
````